# How do I change the resolution of full screen console mode in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, console

Is it possible to change the amount of characters that appear in a full screen cmd.exe from 80X25?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whoa, haven't seen that in a long time ... guess some people can't get away from XP, seemingly.

Anyway, you can do this right from the command line with

```
mode con lines=...
```

and

```
mode con cols=...
```

However, the valid values for both are pretty restricted. I think nowadays you can only choose either 80 × 25 or 80 × 50. But historically there also were 43 lines or 40 columns.

Comment: That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm remembering right, full-screen mode actually changes the display resolution from whatever desktop resolution you have to VGA 80x25 text mode. 80x25 was the DOS mode of preference of yore. I'm pretty sure it can't be changed other than what Johannes pointed out.

Comment: Actually, since the font used in full screen mode had a character size of `9x16` pixels, the actual video mode used to be `720x400`.